# Jquery sliding/animated div

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, sliding

I am trying to figure out how to make a hidden menu slide out with dynamic content when a navigation link is clicked. How can I give this the appearance that the div is sliding out. I think I need to use the 'animate' function, but I am not sure how to implement it. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here is a link to what I am working on.

http://www.scottjraney.com/music-nav/

Answer (score 0):

you can do         :

```
$('div').hide('blind'); // or any other animation
```